# Example of delta one products

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, hedging, delta-hedging

Not sure if this is the right place to ask such question.

1. How close to 1 should the delta be in order for the product to be classified as delta one.
   2.What examples of delta one products are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated by the name, delta one products have a delta of exactly 1 (at least theoretically) with respect to the underlying; moreover, AFAIK the delta has to be constant, *i.e.* a product with optionality that happens to have $\Delta = 1$ for some period won't be classified as delta one (otherwise it would be a nightmare for traders to manage their books!). Some products that come to mind are forwards, futures, [ETFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange-traded_fund)... You might want to take a look at [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_One).